# list of lists to list of tuples without loops or list comprehensions

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of lists, say [[1,2], [2,3], [1,3]] to list of tuples [(1,2), (2,3), (1,3)]. This can be accomplished easily by list comprehensions as

```
[tuple(l) for l in list]
```

This however will be slow for large lists. So I would like to perform the same using pure numpy operations.

**Edit 1** I will try to make it more clear.

I have a function say `foo()` which will return a python list of lists

```
def foo(*args):
   # Do something
   return arr
```

arr will have a list of lists structure `arr = [[a,b], [c,d],...]`.
Each inner list ( e.g `[a, b]`) will be 2 elements long, and arr will contain a large number of such lists (typically larger than 90,000).

I however, require each inner list to be a tuple, for immutability, like

```
arr = [(a,b), (c, d),...]
```

This can be performed using list comprehensions as

```
def result(arr):
    return [tuple(l) for l in arr]
```

However, considering that the list is large, I would avoid this, and use pure numpy functions to accomplish this. (as @hpaulj suggested using arr.view(), see his other method using dict() and zip() in his answer below).

I would like to know if this is feasible or not. If feasible, please tell me how.

Comment: If converting a list of lists to a list of tuples is too slow, you might want to move to a lower level language.

Comment: @miradulo Yes, That is one option. I was wondering if I could keep it python only. Guess I am back to using SWIG.

Comment: If you added what task you are actually doing, there is a chance it could be further optimized.

Comment: @Roy_123 I can't see numpy doing any good here since converting your list to array alone takes longer than your list comprehension.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I can output an numpy array from the function instead of list of lists. So I will not need to convert list to array.

Comment: *"This however will be slow for large lists."*  "Large" is a relative term.  What are typical lengths of the list and of the lists in the list?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser List is a 2D list of lists. Each internal list will be 2 elements long. The total list will contain more than  90,000 such 2 element lists.

Comment: A few days ago some asked something similar, [how to convert numpy array into tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757471/how-to-convert-numpy-array-into-tuple).  Everyone suggests the list comprehension.  I suggest `tolist` first.  Numpy only produces a list of tuples if the array dtype is compound, i.e. a structured array.  But the underlying question is **why**?  What does a list of tuples do for you that a list of lists doesn't?

Comment: I don't see what a lower level language does for us.  List and tuples are Python objects.  `C` code can't construct those without calling Python functions (even in compiled cython code).

Comment: If you actually need `tuple` objects, `numpy` will probably be *slower*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample list, and an array made from it:

```
In [26]: alist = [[1,2], [2,3], [1,3]]
In [27]: arr = np.array(alist)
In [28]: arr
Out[28]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [1, 3]])
```

`tolist` is a relatively fast way of 'unpacking' an array, but it produces a list of lists - just like we started with:

```
In [29]: arr.tolist()
Out[29]: [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 3]]
```

So converting that to a list of tuples requires the same list comprehension:

```
In [30]: [tuple(x) for x in arr.tolist()]
Out[30]: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3)]
In [31]: [tuple(x) for x in alist]
Out[31]: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3)]
```

Now if the array has a compound dtype, the `tolist` does produce a list of tuples.  Conversely, to create a structured array from a list, we need a list of tuples:

```
In [33]: arr1 = np.array([tuple(x) for x in alist], dtype='i,i')
In [34]: arr1
Out[34]: array([(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3)], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [35]: arr1.tolist()
Out[35]: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3)]
```

Constructing a structured array from a 2d array, is kind of tricky:

```
In [37]: arr.view('i,i')
Out[37]: 
array([[(1, 0), (2, 0)],
       [(2, 0), (3, 0)],
       [(1, 0), (3, 0)]], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

`astype` isn't much better.  In fact, more than once I've recommended going the `tolist` route:

```
np.array([tuple(x) for x in arr.tolist()],'i,i')
```

`In[33]` is one case where where a list of tuples matters.  That's because `numpy` developers have chosen to interpret the tuple as a structure array 'marker'.

I can't think of regular Python cases were a list of tuples is required and a list of lists won't do.  Usually the significant difference between tuples and lists is that tuples are immutable.  OK, that immutability does matter when constructing dictionary keys (or set elements).

```
In [42]: dict(zip(alist,['a','b','c']))
....
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
In [43]: dict(zip([tuple(x) for x in alist],['a','b','c']))
Out[43]: {(1, 2): 'a', (1, 3): 'c', (2, 3): 'b'}
```

### corrected `view` conversion to structured array

My earlier attempt at using `view` was wrong because I used the wrong `dtype`:

```
In [45]: arr.dtype
Out[45]: dtype('int64')
In [46]: arr.view('i8,i8')
Out[46]: 
array([[(1, 2)],
       [(2, 3)],
       [(1, 3)]], dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8')])
In [47]: arr.view('i8,i8').tolist()
Out[47]: [[(1, 2)], [(2, 3)], [(1, 3)]]
```

Better - though now I have tuples within lists.

```
In [48]: arr.view('i8,i8').reshape(3).tolist()
Out[48]: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3)]
```

This avoids the list comprehension, but it isn't faster:

```
In [49]: timeit arr.view('i8,i8').reshape(3).tolist()
21.4 µs ± 51.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [50]: timeit [tuple(x) for x in arr]
6.26 µs ± 5.51 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Time tests for creating dictionary from list of lists vs. list of tuples:

```
In [51]: timeit dict(zip([tuple(x) for x in alist],['a','b','c']))
2.67 µs ± 21.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [52]: timeit dict(zip(Out[48],['a','b','c']))
1.31 µs ± 5.96 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Obviously you need to do time tests on realistic problems, but this small example suggests the way that those will go.  Despite all the talk about `numpy` operations being fast(er), list comprehensions aren't that bad, especially if the result is going to be a list of Python objects anyways.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting ndarray.view().