# What is the fastest way to read in an image to an array of tuples?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to assign provinces to an area for use in a game mod. I have two separate maps for area and provinces.
[provinces file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VVha.png),
[area file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQncr.png).
Currently I am reading in an image in Python and storing it in an array using PIL like this:

```
import PIL

land_prov_pic = Image.open(INPUT_FILES_DIR + land_prov_str)
land_prov_array = np.array(land_prov_pic)
image_size = land_prov_pic.size
for x in range(image_size[0]):
    if x % 100 == 0:
        print(x)
    for y in range(image_size[1]):

        land_prov_array[x][y] = land_prov_pic.getpixel((x,y))
```

Where you end up with land_prov_array[x][y] = (R,G,B)

However, this get's really slow, especially for large images. I tried reading it in using opencv like this:

```
import opencv
land_prov_array = cv2.imread(INPUT_FILES_DIR + land_prov_str)
land_prov_array = cv2.cvtColor(land_prov_array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #Convert from BGR to RGB
```

But now `land_prov_array[x][y] = [R G B]` which is an `ndarray` and can't be inserted into a set. But it's way faster than the previous for loop. How do I convert `[R G B]` to `(R,G,B)` for every element in the array without for loops or, better yet, read it in that way?

EDIT: Added pictures, more description, and code blocks for readability.

Comment: Please say concisely what you are actually trying go to do. Also, please re-insert the `import` statements you appear to have removed and also supply your image.

Comment: Perhaps arr.tolist(). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757471/how-to-convert-numpy-array-into-tuple/49757668

Comment: Does it have to tuples?  Images often load as 3d arrays, or something that easily converts to one.  Usually the shape is (m,n 3).  What's this about a `set`?

Comment: How do you create `land_prov_array`?

Comment: The rest of my code takes a tuple in which is why I was hoping to keep it as a tuple. Originally I was checking a list to determine whether or not an RGB value was in it, but that quickly became intractable with larger images so I created a set with the RGB values and used that for checking if an RGB value had been added yet. This is super fast and now the slowest part of the code is loading in the data to the array so I'm trying to speed that part up.

Comment: *"It's getting slow"*... please define "slow". What do you actually want? A list of the unique colours in the image? An array of RGB tuples? Forgetting about tuples and arrays and lists for a minute, what are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2):

It is best to convert the `[R,G,B]` array to tuple when you need it to be a tuple, rather than converting the whole image to this form. An array of tuples takes up a lot more memory, and will be a lot slower to process, than a numeric array.

---

The [answer by isCzech](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74251539/7328782) shows how to create a NumPy view over a 3D array that presents the data as if it were a 2D array of tuples. This might not require the additional memory of an actual array of tuples, but it is still a lot slower to process.

Most importantly, most NumPy functions (such as `np.mean`) and operators (such as `+`) cannot be applied to such an array. Thus, one is obliged to iterate over the array in Python code (or with a `@np.vectorize` function), which is a lot less efficient than using NumPy functions and operators that work on the array as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

For transformation from a 3D array (`data3D`) to a 2D array (`data2D`), I've used this approach:

```
import numpy as np

dt = np.dtype([('x', 'u1'), ('y', 'u1'), ('z', 'u1')])

data2D = data3D.view(dtype=dt).squeeze()
```

The `.view` modifies the data type and returns still a 3D array with the last dimension of size 1 which can be then removed by `.squeeze`. Alternatively you can use `.squeeze(axis=-1)` to only squeeze the last dimension (in case some of your other dimensions are of size 1 too).

Please note I've used `uint8` (`'u1'`) - your type may be different.

Trying to do this using a loop is very slow, indeed (compared to this approach at least).

Similar question here: [Show a 2d numpy array where contents are tuples as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73382388/show-a-2d-numpy-array-where-contents-are-tuples-as-an-image/74248453#74248453)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this produces an actual view, no data is copied, and modifying `data2D` also modifies `data3D`.